# Center div between two other divs

Tags: html, css

I have two div align in two side of my page and I want now that the div between them align in the center.

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nxHet/) I want center the Blue Div.

HTML :

```
<div class="lateral_div" style="float: left"></div>
<div class="center_div" ></div>
<div class="lateral_div" style="float: right"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.lateral_div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.center_div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your markup to this:

```
<div class="lateral_div" style="float: left"></div>
<div class="lateral_div" style="float: right"></div>
<div class="center_div"></div>
```

And then **not** float the middle element, and apply a `margin: 0 auto`:

```
.center_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nxHet/3

Comment: it seems to work thanks man. even if i don't want to change my markup.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `text-align:center` to your `body` (or other parent element) to center inline elements, then unfloat the centered `div` and give it `display:inline-block`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/nxHet/1/)

Revised CSS

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
.lateral_div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.center_div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i have a lot of divs in my parent element and i want to center just one ... this code didn't work.

Comment: @Youssef - you need to provide enough detail in your question to allow those answering to accommodate any eventuality, otherwise you will get only answers to the specific content of your question. Can you add the extra information so we can better see the situation?

Comment: i will try because it's a huge project. i will test your solution and find out where the error come from.

Comment: it works now :) i just drop a `center_div:after` and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Put all div's inside another div and use css style property *display: inline-block;* it will solve your problem

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#left{
 float:left;
 width:100px;
}
#right{
 float:right;
 width:100px;
}
#center{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

use `margin : 0 auto` for center div

Comment: it should work if you have the width defined on the parent container and don't have it floating. I've edited SW4's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxHet/4/